# jQuery: Popup like MSN Messenger

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Do you know a popup in jQuery which work like the popup of MSN Messenger?
I want to display a message at the botton right of the page for example.

Thank you very much

Comment: you mean growl plugin like these: [http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html] (http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html)?

Comment: Perfecto Janez, it's perfect, thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something I came up with using [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Markup:

```
<div id="dialog" title="New Message!" >Hi, How are you?</div>
<button type="button">Check Messages</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    height: 120,
    width: 10,
    draggable: false,
    position: ['right', 'bottom'],
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: 'slide',
        direction: 'up',
        duration: 300
    }
});
$(':button').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog("close").dialog('open');
});
```

Customary [jsFiddle demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/2GaLg/).

Answer (score 0):

try [jQuery Easy Confirm Dialog plugin](http://projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/)